# Why won't save_model override allow HttpResponseRedirect()?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to add an intermediate confirmation page while saving a model that is conditional based on variables of the object being saved. ex, if object status is `draft` and the change will be to `live`, trigger confirmation. Else any other status, just save with no intermediate confirmation.

I added `admin.ModelAdmin` to my models admin class:

```
class SurveyAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
```

And I'm trying to override `save_model` to test conditions and add confirmation if need:

```
@csrf_protect_m
@transaction.atomic
def save_model(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    survey = Survey.objects.get(pk=object_id.id)
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'confirm' in request.POST:
            # do the thing
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:survey_change', args=(survey.pk,)))
        else:
            context = {
                'title': _('Make live'),
                'is_popup': False,
                'opts': self.model._meta,
                'app_label': self.model._meta.app_label,
                'object': survey,
            }
            return TemplateResponse(
                request,
                'admin/survey/make_live_confirmation.html',
                context)
```

**The problem:**

It seems `save_model` ignores my `HttpResponseRedirect` **AND** my `TemplateResponse` returns.

I have this exact process working on other methods inside admin.py, but they are not overrides, they are custom definitions.

Any ideas why `save_model` won't let me take control of the returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

standard `save_model` implementation only performs `obj.save()` and methos that use it (`_changeform_view` and `changelist_view`) do not expect any return value.

If you want change the Request/Response flow you have to look at `changeform_view` for single record updates and `changelist_view` for changelist using `list_editable`

Comment: got it mostly working, but ran in to an error down the line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674750/djando-managementform-error-when-using-custom-intermediate-page-and-changeform-v